# Experience accessing USGS EST services using python?

Tags: python, xml, url

I am writing python code that will be passed gage ID(s) and then generate a REST specific URL to access the instantaneous parameter values I am querying.  I am new to Python, but have got the code working up to the generation of the URL.

I am using the package 'urllib' to access the URL.  But, and here is where it gets foggy, I am assuming that I need to save the response (in WaterML format) to digest later in the code (using the ElementTree XML API).  If this is true, please correct if not, how do I go about it?

```
########################################################################################
# Bulding the USGS REST query using the gage ID 
# Below is temporary overwriting of gage_Id to be that of the of the gage on the Kanawha river by Charleton, WV
gage_ID = "03198000"
# the parameter id of the instantaneous discharge parameter
iq_gage_param = "00060"   # the parameter Id for instantaneous dischagre values form a gage   
# we could list other params and tack them onto the end of the query with a comma "," in between them

query = "http://waterservices.usgs.gov/nwis/iv?format=waterml,2.0&sites=" + gage_ID + "&parameterCd=" + iq_gage_param
# Check
print(query)

response = urllib2.urlopen(query)
```

How do i save the response as a file to later be accessed for parsing?

Comment: It sounds like you need to write some code.  Once you do, feel free to post it here with any questions you have.

Comment: let me know if you need more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the `response` directly to `ElementTree`'s `parse()` method:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = ET.parse(response)

import sys
root.write(sys.stdout)
```

Instead of printing to stdout, you probably want to use `root.find()` and so on to get data from the `ElementTree`.

This whole thing works so easily because the `urllib2` response is a "file-like object" which in Python means it can be read from, and `ElementTree.parse()` accepts a file-like object.  So it flows quite naturally between the two modules, even though they know nothing about each other.